# Powershell - Adds spaces after clearing log file

Tags: powershell

I have script which writes to log file,

At the beginning of the script i added lines to remove X number of first lines and then continue writing to that log

```
# Get number of lines of log file 
$logfileLines = Get-content $LogFile | Measure-Object –Line | select -ExpandProperty Lines

# If number of lines is more than 5000, remove first 4000 lines

if($logfileLines -gt '5000') {

     (Get-Content $LogFile | Select-Object -Skip 4000) | Set-Content $LogFile

  }
  # write something to log file
   filter timestamp {"$(Get-Date -Format G): $_"}
   write-output "############### Starting Script for adding new user ##############" | timestamp >> $LogFile
  Write-Verbose "Connecting to Mailbox" 
  write-output "Connecting to Mailbox" | timestamp >> $LogFile
```

This works fine, log file is truncated, but when script continue writing, for next lines it adds spaces after every character

```
4/15/2020 10:17:10 AM: No emails found, exiting
4 / 1 5 / 2 0 2 0   1 0 : 3 9 : 2 1   A M :   # # # # # # # # # # # # # # #   S t a r t i n g   S c r i p t   f o r   a d d i n g   n e w   u s e r   # # # # # # # # # # # # # # 

 4 / 1 5 / 2 0 2 0   1 0 : 3 9 : 2 1   A M :   C o n n e c t i n g   t o   M a i l b o x 

 4 / 1 5 / 2 0 2 0   1 0 : 3 9 : 2 7   A M :   C o n n e c t i o n   t o   M a i l b o x   f i n i s h e d 

 4 / 1 5 / 2 0 2 0   1 0 : 3 9 : 2 7   A M :   S e a r c h i n g   ' P r o c e s s e d '   f o l d e r . . 

 4 / 1 5 / 2 0 2 0   1 0 : 3 9 : 2 7   A M :   E m a i l   s e a r c h   c o m p l e t e d 

 4 / 1 5 / 2 0 2 0   1 0 : 3 9 : 2 7   A M :   N o   e m a i l s   f o u n d ,   e x i t i n g
```

Tried also to create "temporary" log file, but same results

```
Get-Content $LogFile | Select-Object -Skip 100 | Set-Content "C:\User\temp.log"
      move "C:\User\temp.log" $LogFile -Force
```

Comment: Write-Output passes UTF-16, so the double bytes' zeroes are represented as extra spaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's likely not spaces, but null characters because the strings - which are Unicode in memory, which for ASCII characters consist of the first byte containing the character and the second byte 0x00.

In Windows, this can be a combination of many things including to what the code page is set for the console host (e.g. conhost.exe), as well as the `[Console]::OutputEncoding` for PowerShell and what encoding the file was already using. When calling `Set-Content`, you could use `Set-Content -Encoding Unicode "C:\User\temp.log"` since it seems your `timestamp` program is actually writing Unicode characters to stdout, ignoring to what your console code page is set.

But it would likely be easier to just format the string yourself with the timestamp right into the file and all the default encoding that PowerShell knows will be used.

```bsh
function Log([string] $message) {
  ("{0:G} $message" -f [DateTime]::UtcNow) >> 'C:\User\temp.log'
}

Log 'Connecting to mailbox'
```

If you decide to keep using `timestamp`, either see if you can control it's output encoding (since it's not properly detecting it) or pass Unicode to `Set-Encoding` or `Add-Encoding` - the latter to append content.

Comment: Actually, you found a workaround given the current environment. Out-File defaults to UTF8NoBOM. If you mix different cmdlets that either default to different encodings or detect the current console host encoding while others don't, you'll still get mixed results from writing Unicode vs. ASCII or UTF8. Stick with a single cmdlet or family, like Add/Set-Content with a specified -Encoding, Write-Output / >>, or Out-File. Type `help <cmdlet>` for more information about their encoding behaviors (if nothing, assume Unicode/UTF-16).

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out, changed `Set-Content` to `Out-File`, also, no need to use "temporary" file

```
(Get-Content $LogFile | Select-Object -Skip 100) | Out-File $LogFile
```